# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm trying to push to the another routes but i'm getting this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at eval (JoinRoom.vue?bd9d:74:1)
```

this how i push if successful

```
axios
        .post(`http://localhost:3000/api/chat`, this.chat)
        .then(response => {
          this.socket.emit("save-message", {
            room: this.room,
            nickname: this.nickname,
          });
          this.$router.push({
            path: "ChatRoom",
            params: {
              id: this.$route.params.id,
              nickname: response.data.nickname
            }
          });
        })
```

this is my router

```
  {
    path: '/chat-room/:id/:nickname',
    name: 'ChatRoom',
    component: ChatRoom
  },
```

please how can i go about this

Answer (score 0):

#### At the point that you are calling `this.$router`, it is `undefined`

Make sure you have made the router globally available in your Vue app.

Make sure that this component can "see" your router. The easiest way to check is to add a `mounted` hook to the `JoinRoom` component:

```
mounted() {
  console.log({router: this.$router});
}
```

Report back what that displays.

#### I am assuming the JS code you showed is from `JoinRoom.vue`

Please confirm that it is *inside* the `methods` of the `export default` section of the JS code. Outside that, `this` will not mean what you want it to mean.

Your error message refers to `JoinRoom.vue`.

But you have shown us `ChatRoom.vue`.